# Can background fetch be triggered by push notifications or app open?

Tags: ios, swift, background-fetch

I have a background task handled in performFetchWithCompletionHandler and it has complex logic including API request and iCloud sync. It's working fine by itself but according to user feedbacks/events sometimes it runs in the foreground and it causes some data corruption and concurrency problems.

[image]

**cloud_sync_bg_started** -> Background fetch starts.

**splash_view** -> First ViewController when the app starts.

**ic_document_open** -> Event about related background fetch logic.

I'm assuming that the application is awaking with a push notification and Operating System decides to run the background task at that time and it continues to run after the app opens but I couldn't find anything that proves this.

Can background fetch *(performFetchWithCompletionHandler)* be triggered by push notifications or app open?